# Concept of sinkfunction and its implementation that is richsinkfunction in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to understand the concept of `sinkfunction` and `richsinkfunction`. However, I cannot find a site that explain its underlying concept in detail, but what I found is that its API document.

Who can give me easy explanation of the two function `sinkfunction` and `richsinkfunction` in flink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stream processing pipelines end with a sink; a sink consumes a stream and forwards it to an external system. E.g., it writes the stream to a Kafka topic, or to a rolling set of files, or a database, etc.

All data flows in Flink start with one or more sources, and end with one or more sinks. See the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/concepts/overview/) and the [training](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/overview/) for a more complete conceptual introduction to Flink.

Flink's user defined functions come in two flavors: plain and "rich". These RichFunction interfaces make it possible to hook into more of Flink's runtime; in particular, you can define `open()` and `close()` methods, and use Flink's managed state mechanisms. Rich functions are introduced [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/etl/#rich-functions).

Most non-trivial sinks are RichSinkFunctions because they want to initialize a connection in the `open()` method and tear it down in the `close()`, but a simple sink may not need this.